# If I use the MinWidth / minHeight in my layoutRoot Grid the preview gridlines stop working

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

What am I doing wrong, or is this a bug in **blend 3/Silverlight 3 preview**

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="SideBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="768" MinWidth="100" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection RotationX="0" RotationY="0" CenterOfRotationX="0"/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="3.129,0.55" StartPoint="-1.356,0.198">
                    <GradientStop Color="#C80900FF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the MinHeight in the RowDefinition... like...

```
<RowDefinition MinHeight="768"  Height="*"/>
```